# Gson - Nested Object inside a CustomObject - java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: java, gson

I googled and saw many question and answers but none of it are helping me. Here is the issue. I have a Class

```java
public class ResponseData {

    public static transient final int SUCCESS = 1;
    public static transient final int FAILED = 0;

    public String id;
    public int status;
    public Object data;

    // Constructor, Getters and Setters
}
```

I'm using `ResponseData` as the common return object for my server and the server has many APIs. In one of the API, it is setting the `data` parameter to ArrayList. Then converting as json using Gson (2.8.0).
And then sending back to caller. (It's not HTTP)

```java
public class MyServerClass {

    private final Gson gson;

    public MyServerClass() {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        gson = builder.serializeNulls().create();
    }

    public String someAPI() {
        ResponseData responseData = new Response("myid", ResponseData.SUCCESS, Arrays.asList("Some string value", ArrayList<MyCustomObject>, "Some other Value"));
        String json = gson.toJson(response)
    }
}
```

And the MyCustomClass is a plain POJO class with some set of attributes.

```java
public class MyCustomClass {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String createdTime;
    //Constructor, Getters & Setters
}
```

At the receiving side I have below code.

```java
private Gson gson = null;


GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
gson = builder.create();
///

ResponseData response = gson.fromJson(eventData, ResponseData.class);
ArrayList list = (ArrayList) respone.getData();
String val = (String) list.get(0);
List rwData = (List) list.get(1);

for(List<List<String>> entry: rwData) { // Exception is thrown Here. How to get it as List?
    //Coverting Data
}
```

Exception is thrown when trying to get the data as `List<List<String>>`. How to convert the json string properly here? I cannot use the `MyCustomClass` at my client layer. That's why trying list

```
Exception occured:com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Comment: You are expecting a `List<List<String>>` but are serializing a `List<MyCustomObject>` which becomes a `List<Object>` in JSON.

Comment: At least it should be `List<Map>` as key value pair instead of Object, right? Why not `java.util.Map` instead of gson LinkedTreeMap. ?

Comment: [`LinkedTreeMap`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java) is Gson's internal implementation of a `java.util.Map`, it implements this interface (by extending `java.util.AbstractMap`).